# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in C:\xampp\htdocs\messaging\sub_file\left-col.php on line 68

Tags: php

Hello there is an error that I can not find where to delete or put something. It says Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{', expecting '(' on line 68

below here is my code, It's so hard to see mistakes on either opening or closing tags or If I have made an extra or I lack or I misplaced

I do not know where I need to correct the error, please help

```
<div id="left-col-container">
<div onclick="document.getElementById('new-message').style.display='block'" class="white-back">
<p align="center">New Message </p>
</div>

<?php 
$q='SELECT DISTINCT `receiver_name`,`sender_name`
FROM `messages` WHERE 
`sender_name`="'.$_SESSION['username'].'" OR
`receiver_name`="'.$_SESSION['username'].'"
ORDER BY `date_time` DESC';
$r=mysqli_query($con,$q);
if($r){
    if(mysqli_num_rows($r)>0){
        $counter=0;
        $added_user=array();
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($r)){
            $sender_name=$row['sender_name'];
            $receiver_name=$row['receiver_name'];

            if($_SESSION['username']==$sender_name){
                //add the receiver_name but only once
                //so to do that check the user in array
                if(in_array($receiver_name,$added_user)){
                    //dont add receiver_name because
                    //he is already added
                }else{
                    //add the receiver_name
                    ?>
                    <div class="grey-back">
                    <img src="images/profile.png" class="image"/>
                    <?php echo $receiver_name; ?>
                    </div>
                    <?php
                    //as receiver_name added so
                    ///add it to the array as well
                    $added_user=array($counter=>$receiver_name);
                    //increment the counter
                    $counter++;
                }
            }elseif($_SESSION['username']==$receiver_name){
                //add the sender_name but only once
                //so to do that check the user in array
                if(in_array($sender_name,$added_user)){
                    //dont add sender_name because
                    //he is already added
                }else{
                    //add the sender_name
                    ?>
                    <div class="grey-back">
                    <img src="images/profile.png" class="image"/>
                    <?php echo $sender_name; ?>
                    </div>
                    <?php
                    //as sender_name added so
                    ///add it to the array as well
                    $added_user=array($counter=>$sender_name);
                    //increment the counter
                    $counter++;
                }
            }
            }
        }
    }else{
        //no message sent
        echo 'no user';
    }
}else{
    //query problem
    echo $q;
}

?>



<!-- end of left-col-container -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `}` on line 63 is closing the `if(mysqli_num_rows($r)>0){` before your no user else statement, so that is now the else of `if($r){` which orphans the `echo $q` else statement. If your not using an IDE it would be helpful to you if you did, it can help you solve many of these problems.

Comment: I got it, thank you so much :) God bless you :)